# Java constant names conventions for date formats

Tags: java, constants, naming-conventions

Constant names should be match with this regular expression **'^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'** But I have DateConstant and I think date formats of constants more understandable and readable, if use write them like this:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_yyyyMMdd = "yyyyMMdd";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_yyyy_MM_dd = "yyyy-MM-dd";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_yyyy_MM_dd_Combined = "yyyyMMddHHmm";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MM_yyyy = "dd-MM-yyyy";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MM_yyyy_WITH_DOT = "dd.MM.yyyy";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_mm_dd_yyyy_WITH_SLASH = "MM/dd/yyyy";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_m_d_yyyy_WITH_SLASH = "M/d/yyyy";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_mm_yyyy_WITH_SLASH = "dd/MM/yyyy";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MMM = "ddMMM";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MM_yy = "ddMMyy";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MMM_yyyy = "ddMMMyyyy";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MM_yyyy_COMBINED = "ddMMyyyy";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss_sz = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss_sz_XXX = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"; // with mobile client
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_HH_mm = "HH:mm";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DDTHH_mm_ssZ = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ"; // Google Calendar Format
```

I need some advice and find alternative way to rename these constant names.

Comment: Your constants boil down to `final int ONE = 1;` - what happens if you need to change its value? You would have to change the name as well. Including the value of a constant in the name is bad practice. A field name should represent the meaning, not the value.

Comment: You right @luk2302 DATE_FORMAT_ prefix should be remove. My problem with lowercases. For ex; mm_dd_yyyy_WITH_SLASH is not match above regex, if change them with uppercase than I can't understand in the code which date format using. dd/MM/yyyy or DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @luk2302, including the value of a constant in its name is a bad idea.

However, given your current situation why not just define `Map` that is static and final. It is almost equivalent to all your constants defined and you wouldn't get any warnings from your *IDE* or tools like *sonar*.

In this solution we create 2 maps. The first map contains all the constant values but is defined as `private`. If this is declared public then its values can be altered and defeats the purpose of a `constant`. To overcome this issue we define an `unmodifiable` map which is declared in the last line of the static block. Now by exposing *only* this map no mutation on it is possible.

Try :

```
public class Constant {
    private Constant() { } // Can't create obj of this class

    // map that contains the constans but not exposed
    private static final Map<String, String> mapOfConstants = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // unmodifiable map that is exposed
    public static Map<String, String> unmodifiableMap;

    static {
        mapOfConstants.put("yyyyMMdd", "yyyyMMdd");
        mapOfConstants.put("yyyy_MM_dd", "yyyy-MM-dd");
        mapOfConstants.put("yyyy_MM_dd_Combined", "yyyyMMddHHmm");
        mapOfConstants.put("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MM_yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MM_yyyy_WITH_DOT", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        mapOfConstants.put("mm_dd_yyyy_WITH_SLASH", "MM/dd/yyyy");
        mapOfConstants.put("m_d_yyyy_WITH_SLASH", "M/d/yyyy");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_mm_yyyy_WITH_SLASH", "dd/MM/yyyy");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MMM", "ddMMM");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MM_yy", "ddMMyy");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MMM_yyyy", "ddMMMyyyy");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MM_yyyy_COMBINED", "ddMMyyyy");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss_sz", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss_sz_XXX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"); 
        mapOfConstants.put("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        mapOfConstants.put("HH_mm", "HH:mm");
        mapOfConstants.put("YYYY_MM_DDTHH_mm_ssZ", "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

        // observe this line
        unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mapOfConstants);   
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in another class like :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Constant.unmodifiableMap.get("dd_MM_yyyy_COMBINED");

        // this wouldn't execute
        Constant.unmodifiableMap.put("asd", "asdad");
    }
}
```

You won't be able to use an *enum* either as it would ask you to define the constants as per your question.